# why CountVectorizer doesn't work if used in a function as it should?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

i have a dataset when i use CountVectorizer on it directly it worked well and x have shape (2999, 338)

```
w_O_b = CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
X = w_O_b.fit_transform(spam_data["email"])
```

but when i create a function and use the same code x has a shape of (1,1) , so where is the problem ?

```
def naive(data,label):
      x=data.drop('label',axis=1)
      y=data['label']
      w_O_b = CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
      X = w_O_b.fit_transform(x)
      return X
```

this is the result

<1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Comment: what does your function return?

Comment: i use np.shape(x) just after this code but it has shape (1,1)

Comment: i split data after that using train_test_split but the problem is before that at this step     X = w_O_b.fit_transform(x)

Comment: Add `return` statement

Comment: the function have another code and already have return that's not the whole function

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?